# How to remove meta-data from jql query?

Tags: optimization, curl, filter, metadata, jira

I have the following `curl` command:

```
curl -k -u sandboxer:sandboxer -D- -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data     
'{"jql":"project = BNAP AND resolution = null AND status != Resolved AND status !=    Rejected", 
"maxResults":2 ,
"fields":["KEY","versions","description","status","resolution"]}'
 https://127.0.0.1/rest/api/latest/search 1> newtest
```

I recieve a JSON object with meta-data,

```
{"expand":"schema,names"
,"startAt":0
,"maxResults":2
,"total":74
...
```

All I am intersted in is what follows, `issues`. I could take care of this in my application, but I am wondering if there is a way I could just tell JIRA 'Don't send me meta-data'. Is there?

Comment: Not that I know of, it's part of the defined result of the REST resource. Handling it in your application seems like the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Speakeasy plugin to create a custom request/response as a Jira extension:

- [Speakeasy plugin](https://github.com/mrdon/speakeasy-plugin)
- [Installing Speakeasy](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/Installing+Speakeasy)
- [Developing Speakeasy Extensions](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/Developing+Speakeasy+Extensions)